Best way to think of the space $C^w((0,T); L^p(\mathbb{R})$
Let $f \in C^w((0,T); L^p(\mathbb{R}))$, i.e.
$$\{f \mid f:(0,T) \rightarrow L^p(\mathbb{R}) \textrm{ is weakly continuous}\}.$$
Clearly this means for fixed $t$, $f(t,\cdot) \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$. I am familiar with Bochner spaces, the concept of weak continuity, and (assuming a first-countable topology) its characterization by weakly convergent sequences (i.e. if $g: X \rightarrow Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, then $g$ is weakly continuous if and only if $g(x_n) \rightarrow g(x)$ weakly in $Y$ for all $x_n \rightarrow x$ weakly in $X$).
Based on the above, the way I currently view the space $C^w((0,T); L^p(\mathbb{R}))$ is $f \in C^w((0,T); L^p(\mathbb{R}))$ if and only if $f(t_n, \cdot) \rightarrow f(t, \cdot)$ weakly in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for all weakly convergent $t_n \rightarrow t$. But $(0,T)$ is finite dimensional so weak convergence is the same as norm convergence. Hence I am confused as it seems the only thing "weak" is weak convergence in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$.
There is the more topological definition, where $f \in C^w((0,T); L^p(\mathbb{R}))$ means the preimage of any weakly open set in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ is an open set in $(0,T)$ with the standard topology, but it seems this is not the way most analysts think of or work with these spaces.
What is the best way to think about and work with this space and similar spaces?

Imho the best way to think abou this is your third paragraph. This is equivalent to the second paragraph. Analysists may like the formulation with sequences more because some statements rely on sequences (e.g. dominated convergence).

@daw Thank you for your comment.
